# Dynamic Table to HTML and Sort on multiple columns

Tags: google-fusion-tables, tablesorter

I would like to combine the following

this [table sorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-option-sort-list.html)

and this [fusion table to html table](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Takazudo/WrJkX/)

But after 3 days of working on it I've decided to may be best to ask for help.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: How far have you gotten?  What does the current version of your attempt to make it work look like?

Comment: I didn't get anywhere so all I have are the two examples given.

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/qPDXg/3/

Answer (score 0):

1. include the tablesorter script.
2. Add this to the `<table>` tag:

   ```
   <table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
   ```
3. Add this to the code after the table is populated:

   ```
      $("#myTable").tablesorter();
   ```

[working example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/qPDXg/3/)